# How can I change fragment shader in realtime in three.js?

Tags: three.js, fragment-shader

I did the obvious, but it doesn't work:

```
myshader.fragmentShader = myfragmentshader; //string
```

Comment: Please make question little more respective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/materials/ShaderMaterial):

> Built in attributes and uniforms are passed to the shaders along with
>   your code. If you don't want the `WebGLProgram` to add anything to your
>   shader code, you can use `RawShaderMaterial` instead of this class. You
>   can use the directive `#pragma unroll_loop` in order to unroll a for
>   loop in GLSL by the shader preprocessor. The directive has to be
>   placed right above the loop. The loop formatting has to correspond to
>   a defined standard

The procedure for three.js can be found in the [`RawShaderMaterial`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/materials/RawShaderMaterial) documentation.

This is a good approach because we do it from the material level. This means that you can set it up for each material custom shader and not for all objects in the webGL app.

```
var material = new THREE.RawShaderMaterial( {

    uniforms: {
        time: { value: 1.0 }
    },
    vertexShader: document.getElementById( 'vertexShader' ).textContent,
    fragmentShader: document.getElementById( 'fragmentShader' ).textContent,

} );
```

At runtime just setup material in classic three.js easy style:

```
  object3d.material = raw_mat;
```

Comment: Thanks, but as it is, it didn't work, I had to use 'this' instead of object3d -probably because I define the shaders in a JS file. It took me 2 hours to figure this out...